# LiveScript API-Doc creation?

Tags: livescript, api-doc

With JavaScript I used JSDuck, what should I use for LiveScript?

Seems like comments aren't preserved in the JS-source.

Answer (score 2):

Multiline comments are preserved, as pointed out in the [docs](http://livescript.net/#literals).

> Multiline comments are preserved in the output.

```
/* multiline comments
   use this format and are preserved
   in the output unlike single line ones
*/
```

So you can use whatever tool feels best for you.